# Loading KendoUI Tabstrip Using Partial

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

Does anybody know if it is possible to load a tabstrip by making an Ajax request to a controller that returns a Partial like you can do with a KendoUI Window control?

If not I will simply do an AJAX request to get my PartialViewResult and then set the use jQuery to set the html of the div. But would be good to know if it can be done using the tabstrip API.

I have tried the following as per the KendoUI documentation but it doesn’t seem to work.

```
<div id="tabstrip">
    <ul>
        <li class="k-state-active">Tab 1</li>
        <li>Tab 2</li>
        <li>Tab 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
            animation: { open: { effects: "fadeIn"} },
            contentUrls: [
                        'myController/myAction/id1',
                        'myController/myAction/id2',
                        'myController/myAction/id3'
                    ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Cragly

Comment: Do you return also the script tag with the ajax call? In this case it should work but I think that you must remove the document load event, just call kendo. Just note that in your code div tag is not closed. Also pay attention that the id is not already used.

Comment: I have updated the code example which I have simplified slightly from the code that is used in my application. I just wanted to demonstrate that I'm not loading elements till the DOM is loaded etc. My controller actions returns a PartialViewResult. I am not sure if this is the issue ie can the Tab content deal with what is beeing returned?

Comment: Since you are loading a partial view I think that `$(document).ready(function () {` shouldn't be used. Have you tried to remove it?

Comment: Yes tried that and still nothing

Answer (score 1):

Basically what I would suggest is to initialize the widget (without such content URLs) and then invoke the append method immediately like shown [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/tabstrip#methods-append).

```
tabStrip.append(
[{
    text: "Item 1",
    url: "http://www.kendoui.com"               // Link URL if navigation is needed, optional.
},
{
    text: "<b>Item 2</b>",
    encoded: false,                             // Allows use of HTML for item text
    content: "text"                             // Content for the content element
},
{
    text: "Item 3",
    contentUrl: "partialContent.html"           // From where to load the item content
},
{
    text: "Item 4",
    imageUrl: "http://www.kendoui.com/test.jpg" // Item image URL, optional.
},
{
    text: "Item 5",
    spriteCssClass: "imageClass3"               // Item image sprite CSS class, optional.
}]
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Petur. I got the configuration from KendoUI ajax demo (http://demos.kendoui.com/web/tabstrip/ajax.html) . I tried your code but I am now getting jquery error (Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMDocumentFragment.appendChild]) So not sure if its to do with the version of KendoUI(v2012.2.710) and jQuery (1.9.1) I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a way in the end to get this to work with the control itself so I came up with my own solution to the problem which was to request the partial in an ajax request and then simply update the div content for the specific tab.

```
function loadTabContent() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/myControllerName/Action',
        async: false,
        data: { id: itemId },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#myTabStripTabStrip-2').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Hopefully it may help others who have the same issue.

Thanks again for all that helped me out with this one.

Answer (score 0):

- Inside of each "li" you need to add a "div" and id for each of these divs.
- In the event "select" of the tabStrip you will need to get the div related to this tab clicked. For this example we will call "divContent" the div of the tab clicked.
- Call the ajax request to the controller to get your partiaview. You will get the response of this ajax call and you need to insert inside of your div from the previous step:

> divContent.html(response);

I do it in this way and it works well. You can even add some jquery effect to make look nicer:

> divContent.html(response); //set your response in the div
>   divContent.hide(); //Hide divContent.fadeIn(500); //And fade in the
>   result

I hope it helps

Cheers,
Ricardo